# Dependecy Injection doesn't work with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have a problem with dependecy injection in Azure Functions. I read every guide and any issue here on stackoverflow but I can't found a solution.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 and Azurite for testing in my local machine. I tried to make a project without and It works fine.
The project is an Azure Functions with HttpTrigger.

**Here the link to** [my github repository](https://github.com/andreazanetti92/ZanettiClod.SampleAzureFunctions)

I paste here my Startup's code:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace ZanettiClod.SampleAzureFunctions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Program's code:

```
namespace ZanettiClod.SampleAzureFunctions
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

My GetProducts's Code:

```
namespace ZanettiClod.SampleAzureFunctions
{
    public class GetProducts
    {
        private readonly IProductService _productService;

        public GetProducts(IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

        [Function("GetProducts")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] 
            HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("GetProducts");
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var products = await _productService.GetAllProducts();

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(products);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get back:
[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkekA.png)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: can you add your GetProducts code function?

Comment: The dependency container attempts to resolve all dependencies in the chain so the error could be happening at any level. From what I've seen, the `ProductService` and interface look good, but I'm not sure about the `ProductRepository` constructor. Could you include the full exception and stack trace output?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I added the GetProducts.

Comment: @NathanFoss I Added a screenshot of the complete error at the end of the the question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I'm just curious if there would be any other helpful details in the Visual Studio exception window.

Comment: If you mean the little window that appears beside a line of code I don't have any of it. The error show only in the debug console.

Comment: is this .net core 3.1 or .net 5 ?

Comment: No, It is .net 5

Comment: your repository takes an IConfiguration , it doesn't seem to be added to the DI registration..

Comment: I have to add builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(); ? or it needs something else? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make below changes to make it work. I tested for Dependency injection and it worked.

1. Move dependency injection from startup.cs to program.cs. That's how it works for   target framework .Net 5.0.
   Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

   ```
    namespace ZanettiClod.SampleAzureFunctions
        {


    public class Program
    {


    public static void Main()
        {

                var host = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                    .ConfigureServices(s =>
                    {
                        s.AddHttpClient();
                        s.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();
                        s.AddSingleton<IProductRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
                    })
                    .Build();
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Change the qualifier for _productService from static to readonly in CreateProduct class. Dependency injection doesn't work on static member variables. Also remove static qualifier from your function.

   ```
      public class CreateProduct
    {
        private readonly IProductService _productService;

        public CreateProduct(IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

        [Function("CreateProduct")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("CreateProduct");
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var product = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<Product>();

            _productService.CreateProduct(product);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(
                new
                {
                    Result = true,
                    Message = $"Name: {product.Name}, Price: {product.Price}"
                });

            return response;
        }
    }
   ```

   }